# How do i simulate a click or keydown event?

Tags: javascript, events, keydown

I need to simulate a click or mouse event. I tried various things but the lib i am using doesnt seem to respond to it or does respond but only on specific browsers. ATM i do $('#target').val($('#target2').val()); which works on firefox and opera. Fails on chrome, IE8 and safari.

I could add events to the libs but i wouldnt know which event to add (or how to do it properly). Anyways how do i solve this? basically i am setting the textarea text with .val() and the lib doesnt seem to pick up that event.

Comment: What you mean by "libs"? What library? What you expect to happen when you set the textarea text? `$('#target').val($('#target2').val());` got nothing to do with click or keydown event, it's only setting value of something to be equal to value of something else..

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: yes and as i mention the library i am using doesnt pick up the event. I need to trigger the event for the code to work correctly

Comment: yes to what? You didn't answer any of my questions and none was Yes/No..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the DOM Level 2 Event Model, like:

```
function simulateClick(element) {
  var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
  cb.dispatchEvent(element);
}
```

Demo: http://www.jsfiddle.net/4yUqL/66/

This will truly simulate a mouseclick on an element. Regardless how events were bound.

Comment: That didnt work but KeyboardEvent did :). Accepted! `var evt = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");        evt.initKeyboardEvent("keypress", true, true, null, false, false, false, false, 0, 0);        element.dispatchEvent(evt);`

Comment: @qwertymk: It does for me. In all browsers except IE (8)

Comment: well, I'm not quite sure how many browsers this implement already. FireFox 3.6.13 works well for me.

Comment: @qwertymk: Does this one work for you? I havent tried to make this one FF compatible. http://www.jsfiddle.net/4yUqL/71/

Comment: @qwertymk: strange, the answer link works great for me. The only thing i can think of is javascript is blocked or disabled in firefox or by an addon.

Answer (score 2):

[`.trigger('click')`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) in jQuery might achieve what you're trying to do. It will fire all the handlers attached to the click event.

Comment: OPs use of `.val()` implies jQuery.

Comment: @jAndy, there's what looks like jQuery code in the question though.

Comment: It doesnt work. I suspect it only triggers events obtain through jquery

Comment: Kind of illogical to downvote, but whatever. It will only work on jQuery events, so if you have `$('something').click(function(){});` you can use `$('something').trigger('click');`

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone bumps into this looking for a **framework agnostic** way to fire any HTML and Mouse event, have a look here: [How to simulate a mouse click using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157929/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-using-javascript/6158050#6158050)